# What is the difference in would have vs would have had

Tags: conditional-constructions

I knew i would have to do this

I would have had a good time if you came in the party

Both the sentences above sound correct
But i want some more examples

Comment: Examples of what? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

(Note that people come *to* parties, as in attend a social gathering. Coming *in* a party would be incorrect, or suggest another meaning of *party*, which now mostly is used in the context of a group or *party* of people arriving at a restaurant to be served.)

> I *would have had* a good time if you came to the party

This means that the party has passed, and the person you're talking to did *not* attend the party. The speaker is saying that if the other person had come, they would have enjoyed it. They are also saying that they did not have a good time at the party.

> I *would have* a good time if you came to the party

This mean that the party hasn't happened yet (or is still happening), and the speaker is saying that they will enjoy the party if the other person comes. This could be a slightly awkward way of expressing that they hope the other person comes (since it seems to hinge *their* enjoyment on the *other* person coming). Some more casual ways of expressing something like that would be, for example:

> I hope you can come to the party *or*
>   I hope you can make it to the party

Answer (score 0):

> I **know** I **will** have to do this.
>
> I **knew** I **would** have to do this.

You see, this *would* is *will*, only in the past. This is different from your second example, where *would* is part of a conditional construction.

> I would have been happy if you were near.
>
> I would have run faster if I had better shoes.
>
> I would have had a good time if you had come to the party.

In all these three sentences the construction is *would have* + Past Participle.

Comment: I can't format my answer properly from my phone..